# How to capture emitted signal in same class in Qt creator

Tags: c++, qt

In my Qt creator application im emitting a signal by calling a member function,

```
  void MyWidget::EmitSignal()
  {    
     emit Update();
  }
```

How to track the emitted signal while i call the member function?

Comment: Your description of the problem is not clear for me. Can you edit it or put more details or code?

Comment: @AlexanderTyapkov : I edited ,  pls Refer above

Comment: What do you mean by `track the emitted signal`?

Comment: @jpo38: i want to call another method while its emits the signal

Comment: Why cannot you call another method inside of EmitSignal slot?

Comment: Then, you may accept answer posted by Parviz Rozikov

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
connect(this,&MyWdiget::Update,this,&MyWidget::SomeRecivedSlot);
```

or

```
connect(this,SIGNAL(Update()),this,SLOT(SomeRecivedSlot()));
```

> Follow the above methods and it is working